# Can't we mock private functions in ballerina?

Tags: ballerina

I have created a mock class for testing purposes, and I'm using the test double approach for that. This class has both public and private functions. Public functions are mocked successfully, but private functions are not.

So, can't we mock private functions using Ballerina? Or is there any other way to mock these functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can mock a private function inside a test double class by making the mock private function return some mock value in place of the actual implementation of the private function.

If you are still facing any difficulties please share a sample of your code.

You can use the below resources regarding mocking.

[Ballerina - Mocking](https://ballerina.io/learn/test-ballerina-code/mocking/)

[Object Mocking in Ballerina](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/testerina-mocking-objects/)

[Function mocking in Ballerina](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjkEaG5jyT8)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example to explain further:

*main.bal*

```
public class Calc {
    public function calc(int a, int b) returns int{
        return self.add(a) + self.add(b);
    }
    function add(int a) returns int{
        return a + 5;
    }
}

Calc newCalc = new();

public function calcFunc() returns int {
    return newCalc.calc(3, 4);
}
```

*main_test.bal*

```
import ballerina/test;

public class MockCalc {
    public function calc(int a, int b) returns int{
        return self.add(a) + self.add(b);
    }
    function add(int a) returns int{
        return a + 10;
    }
}

@test:Config {}
public function testCalcFunc() {
    newCalc = test:mock(Calc, new MockCalc());
    test:assertEquals(calcFunc(), 27);
}
```